# PHPStorm CodeStyle Put Space Before and After ->

Tags: php

I am using PHPStrom 8.0.3 and I can't find how to make this possible.

When I was using Aptana editor some time ago, I liked the way it formatted the code. And I am trying to configure phpstorm code style.

I would like to configure phpstorm to change

```
$this->some();
```

to

```
$this -> some();
```

I've checked Settings- > Code Style -> PHP but I couldn't find this anywhere. May be I am missing something. Does anyone know how to put a space before and after ->

Answer (score 0):

Contacted Jetbrains and here is their reply

> Unfortunately, there is no such option in PhpStorm at the moment.
>   However, we already have a related feature request submitted here:
>   https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-12067.